# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_element'

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, attributeerror

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [200], in <cell line: 17>()
     15 sleep(3)
     17 for match in matches:
---> 18     team = matches.find_element(By.XPATH,('//span[@class="team"]')).text
     19     scores = matches.find_element(By.XPATH,('//span[@class="score"]')).text
     20     print(team,scores)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_element'
```

Hi everyone
I have this attribute error on my code , i try to replace find_element by find_elements but it's doesn't works , so what can i do to achieve my looping and scrap every match on the saison 2020/2021  on the official site Premiere league football

This my code bellow :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
website = "https://www.premierleague.com/results?co=1&se=363&cl=-1"
driver.get(website)
sleep(10)
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,('//*[@class="_24Il51SkQ29P1pCkJOUO-7"]/button')).click()
sleep(10)
element2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,('//a[@id="advertClose"]'))
sleep(10)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",element2);
#WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(driver.find_element(By.ID,('//*[@id="advertClose"]')).click()


matches = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//ul[@class="matchList"]//li')

sleep(3)

for match in matches:
    team = matches.find_element(By.XPATH,('//span[@class="team"]')).text
    scores = matches.find_element(By.XPATH,('//span[@class="score"]')).text
    print(team,scores)
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

the problem is here:

```
for match in matches:
team = **matches**.find_element(By.XPATH,('//span[@class="team"]')).text
scores = **matches**.find_element(By.XPATH,('//span[@class="score"]')).text
print(team,scores)
```

you loop over the matches, and instead of writing `match.find_elements`, you wrote `matches.find_element`. (which is the list you are currently loop over)

Comment: I try you fixture but it's doesn't work
I have the new error

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text`

Comment: did you use find_elements? 
find_elements returns a List. and List has no attribute text (yet, an item inside that list MAY have that attribute). you should probably use find_element. or access an index of what find_elements returns

Comment: thanks @CsgoHost i found my mistake thanks to your help